# rails application command

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

According to output from "rails" command, there is "rails application" command. When I use it I see the output from "rails new" command.

...

```
Description:
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Mb I`m doing something wrong? Or these commands do the same?
Sorry for my bad writing.

Answer (score 0):

`rails application` is not a valid command.

The `rails` command line tool will print out the man page if an invalid command is given. Most command line tools do the same.

Run `rails nonexistent_command` and it will print out the man page.

If outside of a rails app, it will print the man page for `rails new`. If inside a rails app dir, it will print out the other possible commands. e.g `rails generate`, `rails console`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but why `rails application` is not valid command? I can see it if I run `rails` command inside a new application and see:
    
`application  Generate the Rails application code`